# Somehow my BIOS change the boot up device automatically to an external drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, bios

I have a computer with the BIOS configured to boot from an internal storage SSD (with Ubuntu as OS) and there is another external storage SSD (the main purpose of this one is to store some data).

Randomly the BIOS changes the configuration and tries to boot from the external storage, even if it is not connected physically to the computer.

Any ideas on how to avoid this change in configuration?

EDIT: The motherboard, vendor id, etc are set as `default string`
by running `sudo demicode | more` I get:

```
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.2.0 present.
Table at 0x8C9BF000.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 26 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
    Version: 5.13
    Release Date: 10/09/2021
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 16 MB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        BIOS ROM is socketed
        EDD is supported
        5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
        UEFI is supported
    BIOS Revision: 5.13
```

and `uname -a` gives:

```
Linux pc 5.15.0-50-generic #56~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 27 15:51:29 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: could it be random bios factory resets? any chance the BIOS battery is bad/dodgy? maybe replace the bios battery and check if the problem persists?  *on many laptops, replacing the bios battery is really hard

Comment: What are the computer and motherboard models? You might update the BIOS to the latest version. If you already have that version, go into the BIOS and find the Reset button to reset to defaults. Ensure also that the power supply is good.

Comment: By "BIOS battery", I think @hanshenrik is referring to the CMOS battery.  By BIOS, I think we are actually referring to UEFI firmware.  BIOS has not existed for a long while but still gets used as a term.  I am not trying to be the "term police".  I am only trying to educate.  People will continue to use the term howbeit inaccurate.

Comment: This ^^^and while at that it's also fundamental to understand the with UEFI came the UEFI boot mode although many boards still to this day support the old BIOS boot mode (now called "Legacy" or "CSM"). There's no point in forcing this mode unless the OS lacks support for UEFI mode (any major Linux distro supports UEFI mode for over a decade and Windows XP was the last Microsoft OS to support BIOS/Legacy only). Knowing this and still thinking about booting "drives" is a relic of the past. (...)

Comment: (...) UEFI boots .efi files existing in the ESP (EFI System Partition), NOT drives (BIOS indeed booted from the MBR, not so with the modern process). So, whatever is happening it's something else, NOT that it "tries to boot from the external storage". Please check UEFI serttings > Boot and confirm in "OS selction". If by and unfortunate chance you installed the OS(es) in Legacy mode that was a dumb move and the beginning of your current predicament.